# Ansys Workbench, defining ambient temperature correctly

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench

this is probably a beginner's question. I have a simple solid material, lets say wood wall. I am performing transient-thermal analysis. On one side, I have elevated temperatures (after 30 minutes, I already have some 750 degrees Celsius). On this side of wall I defined convection and radiation. Film coefficient is constant, the ambient temperature I defined using a table with values. The same I did for the radiation (in this case I defined constant emissivity and used same temperature table as for convection).

On the other side I have only ambient temperature. So, the temperature at time 0 is 25 degrees Celsius and should go up over the time. This is defined under Initial temperature. I also specified convection and radiation of the wood on the other side, and here is the problem. I defined convection again (this time the film coefficient and temperature is constant, 25 degrees Celsius) and radiation as well (again, the temperature and emissivity are constant).

Since the elevated temperatures of the first side are getting pretty high over the time, it is logical to expect higher temperatures on the other side of wood wall (on its surface at least). However, when I got results, the temperature stays at 25 degrees Celsius whole time.

Is there a way to define just the initial ambient temperature on the "cold" side of wall? I do not want to limit the temperature on the cold side, on contrary, I want to see how high the temperature can get on that side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the possibility of the simulation going wrong can be in two places.

- Firstly, you chose the material to be wood, which is not a good conductor. This means heat is more likely to dissipate from the face rather than distributing itself in the entire part.
- Secondly, if you entered the face temperature on the other side to be 25°C, it will be constant throughout the time period. So you might was well check your setup again.
- Personally, I suggest you to change the material to a good conductor (say a metal) and repeat the simulation.

Thanks